# Access/Change Gitlab option via rest api: "Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm unable to figure out how to access this option via rest api:

Project settings -> CI/CD -> Token Access -> Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project

Is there anyway to change it via an API rather than using the WebGUI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it can be done from the GraphQL API, see the inboundJobTokenScopeEnabled setting at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/index.html#mutationprojectcicdsettingsupdate

Comment: Thanks, Not exactly, it is `Mutation.ciJobTokenScopeAddProject` from GraphQL